# Replacing value at specific location in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a piece of code that checks for NaN or zeros in a particular column and replaces them with a mean of the value recorded by other devices at the same timestamp. However, while everything seems to be working correctly, the last two lines do not seem to replace the value in the ORIGINAL dataframe. Anyone can help?

```
wind_data=pd.read_excel(filename,index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
turb_list=pd.Series(list(set(wind_data['Device'])))
for i in range(len(turb_list)):
    wind_series=wind_data[(wind_data['Device']==turb_list[i])]
    wind_series_neg=wind_data[(wind_data['Device']!=turb_list[i])]
    
    wind_series_index=np.logical_or(np.isnan(wind_series['Wind speed (m/s)']),wind_series['Wind speed (m/s)']==0)
    #if wind_series_index.any()==False:
        #continue
    wind_series_select=wind_series[wind_series_index]
    
    for timestamp in wind_series_select.index:
        wind_data[(wind_data['Device']==turb_list[i])]['Wind speed (m/s)'][timestamp]=wind_series_neg.loc[timestamp]['Wind speed (m/s)'].mean()
```

Dataframe (wind_data) example:

```
Date Device Power ac (kW)   Wind speed (m/s)
2021-11-01 00:00:00 WTG01   466 6.88
2021-11-01 00:00:00 WTG04   555 7.5
2021-11-01 00:00:00 WTG05   226 4.93
2021-11-01 00:00:00 WTG02   522 7.33
2021-11-01 00:00:00 WTG03   409 6.07
2021-11-01 00:10:00 WTG05   262 5.69
...
```

Comment: Can you post the actual dataframe, as in expected and actual output?

Comment: Edited with an example of wind_data. Basically I want to take the zeros or NaNs in Wind speed (m/s) column and exchange them for a mean value of all other devices' wind speed at that timestamp.